# Connect to SQL Server using .NET Framework 4.7.2 Web API 2.0 and without using Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-web-api2, .net-4.8

I have created a Web API built on .NET Framework 4.7.2. I want to be able to communicate with SQL Server without using Entity Framework.

`Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` and `System.Data.SqlClient` are not compatible with .NET Framework 4.7.2. I really do not want to use any ORM.

Any suggestions?

Comment: SqlConnection and related classes are built into .NET Framework, you don't need to add anything.

Comment: ADO.NET, in System.Data.SqlClient

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient does not work with .NET Framework4.7.2.  Here is the information on that.  https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/14880 - System.Data.SqlClient 'not supported on this platform' on Framework 4.7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dapper for example:

```
var data = new List<DapperTest>();
        using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Analysis"].ConnectionString))
        {
             data = db.Query<DapperTest>("select * from testTable").ToList();
        }
        return data;
```

Comment: So I stated that I did not want to use an ORM.  Also, I see that your code is utilizing SqlConnection which is exactly the problem I am running into.  As stated above System.Data.SqlClient, which provides SqlConnection object, is not available in .net framework 4.7.2.

Comment: github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/14880 - System.Data.SqlClient 'not supported on this platform' on Framework 4.7.2

Comment: Okay, I just checked Microsoft documentation and It clearly shows it still included.  I don't understand why my application cannot see the SqlConnection object.  I have System.Data.SqlClient in my using statements and everything.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I build a .net Standard library instead of a .net Framework library.